# Rename fate-fae to fate-accelerated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I propose that we rename [fate-fae](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-fae) to [fate-accelerated](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-accelerated).

[Fate Accelerated](http://www.evilhat.com/home/fae/) is the proper name of the system; FAE is the initialism for Fate Accelerated Edition. Changing the tag to [fate-accelerated](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-accelerated) makes for a more readable tag and avoids an expansion of “Fate Fate Accelerated Edition”. If desired, we could also have [fae](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fae) be a synonym for [fate-accelerated](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-accelerated).

I suggested this in chat and got a handful of agreement with no detractors.

Comment: +1 for eliminating redundant acronyms.

Comment: Great suggestion.

Comment: Done.  People had already retagged, but there's a synonym in place in case anyone tries to use fate-fae in the future.

Comment: Synonymising [tag:fae] may cause problems as I've seen 'fae' used as an alternate spelling of 'fey' in some systems. As long as there's a decent tag wiki it should be fine though.

Answer (score 11):

I'm in support of this . [fate-fae](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-fae) did strike me as a bit odd, since it's repeating itself, but [fae](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fae) might be missed by some. [fate-accelerated](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-accelerated) is perfect.